# GPU running at 20% of expected speed

Tags: mining, gpu, claymore

I have just stuck an old card that I had in my computer to see how much increase in mining speed I would get.

I had a PC with a GeForce GTX 1080Ti in and had a couple of GTX 970 cards lying around so I installed one in the computer.

Using the Claymore miner in single mode with just the 1080Ti I was getting around 30 Mh/s
With the new card installed I get around 34 - 35 Mh/s on the 1080i (weird that has got faster) but only 3 Mh/s on the 970.

According to this [page](https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/asus/nvidia-geforce-gtx-970-ethereum-mining/) the 970 should get around 15 Mh/s

Does anyone have any ideas as to why the second card is running so slow?

I am thinking that for only 3 Mh/s it's probably not worth the extra power and heat buildup.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is somewhat of a known issue with some versions of Windows and some Nvidia Cards.

To solve it I installed Windows 7 instead of Windows 10 and I was back to 30 MH/s

Comment: Please mark your own answer as correct :-)

Answer (score 0):

The Gibabyte Gtx 970 provides hashrate of 22 MHash/s for Ethereum at Coreclock 1563 while consuming 185 watts.
for more information check it out given below link : 
https://miningchamp.com/gpus/38/Gibabyte-Gtx-970-hashrate